# Text with specified FontSize looks smaller than expected

Tags: graphics, text, fonts

The simplest way to see what the post's title is trying to convey is to evaluate:

```
{"-0.5",
  Text[Style["-0.5", FontFamily -> $DefaultFont[[1]],
           FontSize -> $DefaultFont[[2]]]]}
```

On my Windows 7 laptop, at least, the first `0.5` looks larger than the second one.  (The first one looks "right" to me somehow).

My understanding is that `$DefaultFont` specifies the default output font, so I'm puzzled by the obvious difference (illustrated by this example) between text using the default output font, and text using a font explicitly set to match `$DefaultFont` (i.e., the first and second elements in the output of the evaluation above).

Clearly my understanding is wrong somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Ultimately, I'm looking for a reliable way to specify the font size and font family of text elements in `Graphics` generated by `Plot`, etc.

FWIW, I'm using version 9.0.1.0.

Comment: `$DefaultFont` is obsolete, and if you change it substantially (both family and size, e.g. `$DefaultFont={"Times", 20};`), you will see that the output does not use it at all. To style plot texts, use the `Plot` options `LabelStyle`, `FrameTicksStyle`, `DefaultStyle`, `BaseStyle`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As István Zachar noted in his comment, `$DefaultFont` is deprecated. Setting the `BaseStyle` option is the way to go. For example. I frequently set the following options.

```
SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold}];
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold}];
```

Note, I don't monkey with font size. I prefer to let *Mathematica* vary font size as it sees fit.

Now let's look at what difference setting `BaseStyle` makes in the case of a simple plot.

```
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "It's all a plot (pun intended)"]
```

[image: SinPlot.1.png]

```
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "It's all a plot (pun intended)"]
```

[image: SinPlot.2.png]

Note that `BaseStyle` affects all the text in the plot, even the tick labels.